# Shortest Identifying Substring

Tags: code-golf

[image]

This challenge is inspired by [dmenu](http://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/), the program I use to launch other programs on my Linux box. To start, for example, GIMP, I simply hit the keyboard shortcut I have assigned to dmenu, type "gimp" and hit enter. However, I don't have to type the whole name. On my machine, if I type "gim", that's enough. Here's how dmenu decides which program to launch when you hit enter<sup>1</sup>:

1. Find all program names that contain the input as a substring.
2. Sort this list alphabetically.
3. Take the items in the list that *begin* with the input, and (preserving their order) put them at the beginning.
4. Launch the first<sup>2</sup> program in the list.

While this is usually quite convenient, it is sometimes annoying. For example, on my computer I have `chromedriver` and `chromium`. I never want to launch `chromedriver`, but it's earlier alphabetically than `chromium` is. If I start typing at the beginning of the word, like I naturally want to do, I have to type six characters to specify that I mean the latter.

However, we don't need to start typing at the beginning of the word! `chromium` is, alphabetically, the first program name containing the substring `iu`. I have no programs that start with `iu`. Therefore, I only need to type those two characters to unambiguously specify which program I want.

For this challenge, your program or function will receive at least two lines of input. No line will contain any whitespace characters (other than the newline, obviously) and the first line is guaranteed to be repeated somewhere in the remaining input. Your program or function will output (stdout, `return`, etc.) the shortest string that, using dmenu's rules, would find that first line in all the rest. If there are two or more that are tied for shortest, you may output whichever you like.

## Examples

```
In:
bbbb
aaaa
bbbb
cccc

Out:
b

In:
bc
bc
aaaa
bbc

Out:
bc
```

---

<sup>1: I don't actually know this to be the case, but in my experience it seems to work this way.

2: When actually using dmenu, you can hit left and right to choose different items in the list, but that's irrelevant for this challenge.</sup>

Comment: For example 1, unless I'm misunderstanding things, shouldn't the output be `b`?

Comment: @isaacg Yep, I changed the test and didn't fix the output. mb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
hfqzho>xNT0Sf}TY.z.:z
```

isaacg and me got the same 21 solution more or less at the same time. So he deleted his solution.

Try it online: [Pyth Compiler/Executor](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hfqzho%3ExNT0Sf%7DTY.z.%3Az&input=bc%0Abc%0Aaaaa%0Abbc&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
                         implicit:  z = first input line
                                   .z = all other input lines
 f                .:z   filter all substrings T of z, which satisfy:
            f   .z        filter .z for lines Y, which satisfy:
             }TY            T in Y   
           S              sort these lines alphabetically
     o                    order these lines N by:
      >xNT0                 (index of T in N) > 0
                          (sorting in Pyth is stable, so this brings the lines,                      
                           which start with T, to the beginning
                           without messing up the alphabetically order)
  qzh                     z == first element of ...
h                       print first elment
```

Comment: `hfqzho!!xNTSf}TY.z.:z`